# Primary key isn't incremented automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to modify the PK in my table to change the data type of the key from int to nvarchar.
I changed it back to int but I lost some of the key's properties.

The primary key was auto increment but now when I am trying to add a new record without assigning a specific number to the PK, it sets the key to null value which prevent the record from being inserted.

[image]

Is there any way I can set the key to auto increment again?

[image]

I am using SQL server.
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: `Varchar` or `NVarchar` data type field can not be set to auto increment (an identity key). So, when you are inserting new records it is not incrementing automatically.

Comment: I am aware of that, I changed back to int but now it's not auto increment anymore. Thank you

Comment: You need to set the identity to that column again.

Comment: Can you please explain how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the table in the design mode then select the column and enable the identity property as shown in the image.

seed

Is the value that is used for the very first row loaded into the table.

increment

Is the incremental value that is added to the identity value of the previous row that was loaded.

You must specify both the seed and increment or neither. If neither is specified, the default is (1,1).

*Note: If your table contains data already so the value of seed would be the max value of that column + 1.*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the identity to that column again.

**First** Remove Constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Driver
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_Driver;
```

follow a photo to find the name of the Constraint:

[image]

**then** remove primary key column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Driver 
DROP COLUMN DriverId;
```

**finally** Add Primary key column again:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Driver
   add DriverId INT IDENTITY(1,1)
       CONSTRAINT PK_Driver PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED;
```

Comment: 'PK_Drivers' is not a constraint.
Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors. I'm getting this error when I try to do the first query.

Comment: The name of your constraint is different.please view picture.

Answer (score 1):

**DriverId is the first column in the table. You cannot ALTER Column and make it as identity.**

You have two choices.

**1. If you want DriverId to remain as first column in the table**

1. Create new table with same schema as existing table

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Drivers_new
(
DriverId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
firstName ...
lastName ...
.
.
)
```

2. Load data from existing table to new table

```sql
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON dbo.Drivers_new

INSERT INTO dbo.Drivers_new(DriverId,firstName,lastName...)
SELECT DriverId, firstName, lastName ...
FROM dbo.Drivers

SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF dbo.Drivers_new
```

3. Rename old table to backup table and new table as old table

```sql
sp_rename 'dbo.Drivers', 'Drivers_old'
sp_rename 'dbo.Drivers_new', 'Drivers'
```

**2.If you are fine to have DriverId as another column in the end**

1.Drop current column and recreate with identity. Now the DriverId column will be added in the end

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Drivers DROP COLUMN DriverId
ALTER TABLE dbo.Drivers ADD DriverId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```