# Auto increment syntax errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl

Here's the code to my simple database:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User_Info] (
[Username]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Password]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Firstname] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Lastname]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Email]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Country]   NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Phone]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Gender]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Admin]     INT           NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Username] ASC)
);
SELECT GO * from User_Info;

Alter table User_Info
add column id int NOT NULL auto_increment Unique Key;
```

The error for this `CREATE` is:

> Only 1 statement is allowed per batch, such as 'GO', might be required between statements

and the error for the `column` is:

> Incorrect syntax near 'column'

I need an auto ID system so I can progress with my site, how can I fix this mess?

Comment: Keyword **column** is redundant.

Comment: @ScrappyCoco what does it mean when a word is redundant?

Comment: Additionally, specify the keyword `IDENTITY` instead of `auto_increment` in SQL Server. I'd post the proper code but cannot copy/paste your from the image. Always post code as text instead of images.

Comment: @DanGuzman gotcha. I'll edit the post with a copy & pastable code.

Comment: The syntax you have for auto_increment is for mysql - not t-sql.. Are your tags wrong?

Comment: @PeterSmith I figured that there shouldn't be much of a difference, well I was clearly wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code worked for me:

```
CREATE TABLE user_Info (
   [admin] int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   [Username]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   [Password]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   [Firstname] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   [Lastname]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   [Email]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   [Country]   NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   [Phone]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
   [Gender]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: will the "IDENTITY(1,1)" make it automatic?

Comment: @kfir ezer Yes.The MS SQL Server uses the IDENTITY keyword to perform an auto-increment feature.

In the example above, the starting value for IDENTITY is 1, and it will increment by 1 for each new record.

Comment: if you created your table.You need to set the identity to that column again.Follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61473194/5576498

Comment: I changed the [admin] to [id], and the PRIMARY KEY to NOT NULL, and it worked flawlessly. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code for T-SQL is:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.UserInfo (
    UserName nvarchar(50) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserName ASC)
);
SELECT * FROM UserInfo;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.UserInfo ADD id int not null  IDENTITY(1,1);
```

However, it might be preferable to make `id` your primary key and add a constraint to user name if you want that to be unique.

Comment: I get an error in the "CREATE" word, and in the "id" word.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a batch separator, and remove `column` keyword, and replace  `auto_increment Unique Key` with `identity(1,1) unique`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User_Info] (
[Username]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Password]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Firstname] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Lastname]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Email]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Country]   NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Phone]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Gender]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Admin]     INT           NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Username] ASC)
);
GO
SELECT * from User_Info;
GO
Alter table User_Info
add id int identity(1,1) not null unique;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

When adding the column, specify `IDENTITY` along the a `UNIQUE` constraint specification to ensure unique values independent of the primary key. The example below also specifies a constraint name, which is a best practice instead of auto-generated constraint names.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User_Info] (
    [Username]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Password]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Firstname] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Lastname]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Email]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Country]   NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Phone]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Gender]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Admin]     INT           NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Username] ASC)
);

ALTER TABLE dbo.User_Info
    ADD id int NOT NULL IDENTITY CONSTRAINT UQ_User_Info_id UNIQUE;
GO
```